# How tell CP-SAT to set decision variables with some preferences?

Tags: python, or-tools, operations-research, cp-sat

I have a problem with Boolean decision variables.

```
Customer1Accept (True/False)    
Customer2Accept (True/False)  
...
```

Each customer has a score:

```
Customer1score=100  
Customer2score=50  
...
```

Each customer can be marked as `good` or `bad`:

```
Customer1Bad=false  
Customer2Bad=true  
...
```

Each customer asks for money:

```
Customer1money=10.000$  
Customer2money=30.000$  
...
```

The goal is the maximal sum of customer money.
The constraint is that the number of accepted customers marked as `bad` should be below 3.8%

My question is how can I tell to the solver to choose the customers `bad` to be accepted sorting them by score until the 3.8% constraint is satisfied? In other words I would like to take the best customers.

Comment: For the percentage constraint, can't you precalculate how many customers is 3.8%? And for the score, you could add implications such as Customer2Accept => Customer1Accept (because customer2 has lower score)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you explain what do you mean for  Customer2Accept => Customer1Accept? The problem is that I have a boolean variable for each customer and I have to say "set the CustomerXXAccept to true starting from customer from higher to lower score to be sure that I'm choosing the "best" Bad customers"

Comment: What I mean is that you could use AddBoolAnd with OnlyEnforeceIf so that a customer is accepted only if all higher score customers are accepted

Comment: got the point....it works! Thank you!!!